# Read a Web Service output and write it to CSV in Perl

Tags: perl, csv, get

I am trying to read the output of webservice and write to a csv file. The source has many fields and it is quoted with comma delimiter.
A few columns have values on a new line too.
213,"Dan","This is kool","dblee"
214,"Taylot","This is,
not mine","typelee"

Output
213,"Dan","dblee"
214,"Taylot","typelee"

Here I am trying to use get to capture of the output of WS. But facing a problem while trying to read individual fields.This ($csv->getline($fh1)) is not returning an array.
How to make it to return an array. Any inputs.

```
use Getopt::Long; 
use File::Copy; 
use Text::CSV; 

my $filename  = '/mydir/file.txt'; 
my $filename2 = '/mydir/file_formatted.csv'; 

unlink $filename; 

for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= 2 ; $i++ ) 
{ 
   $WS_URL = "https://adesfhr.com/wpi.php?cmd=dsd&PageNumber=$i&pageSize=10&responseType=csv"; `
my $resp = $SSO->get($WS_URL); `
my $data = $resp->content(); `
last if ! $data; `
if ($data) { 
      my $csv = Text::CSV->new( 
       { 
          binary    => 1,      # Allow special character. Always set this 
             auto_diag => 1,      # Report irregularities immediately 
             sep_char  => ',',    #Separatrp 
         } 
     ); 
     open( my $fh1, "<:encoding(utf8)", \$data ) or die "$!"; 
     open( my $fh2, '>>', $filename ) 
       or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!"; 

<$fh1>; 
     while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh1) ) { 

             my $newrow = splice( @$row, 0, 3 ); 
             print "@$newrow\n"; 
             $csv->print( $fh2, $newrow ); 
     } 
     close $fh2; 
     close $fh1; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving any data at all?  URLs don't start with `www.`.

Comment: add debug print to see what is $row. print Data::Dump::dump(\$row).

Comment: while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
      print "Name:  $row->[0]\n\tContact: $row->[4]\n";
      }
  close $fh;

Comment: Its printing. When I use

Comment: Its printing. print $fh2 "$row->[0]|$row->[1]....."

Comment: But the issue is , the columns are not retrieved proper because they have embedded comma or new letter. I want to retrieve in my CSV the column values with quotes as it is present in the input file. Any solution to that